# I/O how can i put somehing in screen withouth being string?

Tags: haskell

So im doing this function and i need her to display on the screen the result of (premio ap x) , the problem is that (premio ap x)::Maybe Int , so its not a string.

```
   joga :: Aposta -> IO ()

    joga x= do
            ap <- leAposta;
            let arroz = (premio ap x)
            putStr  ^^^^^^^^^^
            return ()
```

How can i convert this to a string? Or there is another way to display on the screen things that are not strings.

---

update :full code

```
  comuns :: Aposta -> Aposta -> (Int,Int)
  comuns (Ap a (b,c)) (Ap k (l,ç)) = (cnum a k, cnum [b,c] [l,ç])


  cnum::[Int]->[Int]->Int
  cnum [] l2 = 0
  cnum (x:xs) l2 | elem x l2 = 1 + cnum xs l2
           |otherwise = cnum xs l2


  premio :: Aposta -> Aposta -> Maybe Int
  premio l1 l2 | x == (5,2)= Just 1
         | x == (5,1)= Just 2
         | x == (5,0)= Just 3
         | x == (4,2)= Just 4
         | x == (4,1)= Just 5
         | x == (4,0)= Just 6
         | x == (3,2)= Just 7
         | x == (2,2)= Just 8
         | x == (3,1)= Just 9
         | x == (3,0)= Just 10
         | x == (1,2)= Just 11
         | x == (2,1)= Just 12
         | x == (2,0)= Just 13
         |otherwise = Nothing
where 
    x = comuns l1 l2



   leAposta :: IO Aposta
   leAposta = do 
        putStrLn "Insira como lista as 5 estrelas"
        num <-getLine
        putStrLn "Insira em par as 2 estrelas"
        es<-getLine
        let ap = (Ap (read num) (read es))
        if (valida ap) 
            then return ap
        else do 
            putStrLn "Aposta invalida"
            leAposta
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `arroz` is `premio ap x` which has type `Maybe Int`, you can simply `print arroz`.

`print` works on any type that can be printed, i.e. on those types in class `Show`.

(You probably don't want to use `print` on values that are already strings, though, since that will print the *escaped* string, with quotes around. Use `putStr` and `putStrLn` for strings.)

Comment: it tells me that there is no instance for (Show (Aposta -> IO ()))

Comment: That's because you are not trying to print a `Maybe Int` as you wrote in the question, you are trying to print some function, and functions can not be printed. E.g. if you are trying to `print joga`, that will trigger that arrow. You should post all the relevant code in your question, otherwise it becomes impossible to debug.

Comment: so what are u saying is that im not trying to show the result of (premio ap x) ? im showing premio?

Comment: I have no idea: you wrote that `premio ap x` is of type `Maybe Int`, but the error shows a different type. Something is wrong, but I can't see from the posted code, only.